# Saving checkbox (boolean) values in mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, boolean

I'm trying to save the checkbox value .. I'm doing a enrollment system with a checkbox form. It's function is to know if the student pass the requirement, so I assign it as a boolean type. It must save the value of '1' if the checked and '0' if unchecked.

and the error are:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 2
```

and if I uncheck one of the requirement this is what happen:

```
Notice: Undefined index: brigada_form in C:\xampp2\htdocs\es\add_newstud.php on line 12
Notice: Undefined index: two_picture in C:\xampp2\htdocs\es\add_newstud.php on line 18
```

I really need some help. Here is the code..

Sample form: 1 set the value as '1' and the default value in my database is '0'

```
<input type="checkbox" name="two_picture" id="two_picture" value="1" />
```

php code add_newstud.php

```
$requirement_id = $_POST['requirement_id'];     
$enrollment_form = $_POST['enrollment_form'];
$report_card = $_POST['report_card'];
$brigada_form = $_POST['brigada_form'];
$physical_inspection_form= $_POST['physical_inspection_form'];      
$agreement_upon_enrollment = $_POST['agreement_upon_enrollment'];
$nso = $_POST['nso'];
$good_moral = $_POST['good_moral'];
$one_picture = $_POST['one_picture'];       
$two_picture = $_POST['two_picture'];

$insert_req = "INSERT INTO es_req_newstud(requirement_id,enrollment_form,report_card,brigada_form,physical_inspection_form,agreement_upon_enrollment,nso,good_moral,1x1_picture,2x2_picture) `VALUES` ('$requirement_id','$enrollment_form','$report_card','$brigada_form','$physical_inspection_form','$agreement_upon_enrollment','$nso','$good_moral','$one_picture','$two_picture)";
mysql_query($insert_req) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Hello,

At the end of your query you have a missing ' (after picture).
----->
,'$two_picture)"

Comment: oh thank you.. but there is still an error You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 2  i don't know whats wrong..

Comment: Why is `VALUES` wrapped like that? I would suggest just: `INSERT INTO es_req_newstud(requirement_id,enrollment_form,report_card,brigada_form,physical_inspection_form,agreement_upon_enrollment,nso,good_moral,1x1_picture,2x2_picture) VALUES ('$requirement_id','$enrollment_form','$report_card','$brigada_form','$physical_inspection_form','$agreement_upon_enrollment','$nso','$good_moral','$one_picture','$two_picture')`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, MySQL extensions are deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

If you must use MySQL, I would advise:

```
$insert_req = sprintf("INSERT INTO es_req_newstud (requirement_id,enrollment_form,report_card,brigada_form,physical_inspection_form,agreement_upon_enrollment,nso,good_moral,1x1_picture,2x2_picture) VALUES ('%d','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%d','%d');",
    $_POST['requirement_id'],
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['enrollment_form']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['report_card']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['brigada_form']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['physical_inspection_form']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['agreement_upon_enrollment']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nso']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['good_moral']),
    $_POST['one_picture'],
    $_POST['two_picture']
);
mysql_query($insert_req) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will help ensure that no SQL Injection occurs. Again, I would strongly advise moving to MySQLi or PDO.